# Reading records with partly undefined size from file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Let's say I have a struct

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  char b;
  vector<int> c;
}
```

I would like to write a function, that will read vector < foo> from file bar.txt:

```
1 b 12 34 54
4 z 1 154
6 G 1 1 1 1
```

i. e. size of c for each foo is unknown in advance and may differ, delimiter between foo-s is '\n' character.

The only possibility I see is reading line-by-line into a string and somehow parsing it into foo, but it seems highly awkward. Is there any possibility of performing 'read-ints-until-eol' without that shamanic stuff?

Comment: What "shamanic stuff"? Reading line by line and using a stringstream seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& is, foo& obj) {
    if (!(is >> obj.a))
        return is; // failed
    if (!(is >> obj.b))
        return is; // failed
    obj.c.clear();
    for (int temp; is >> temp; ) {
        obj.c.push_back(temp);
    }
    return is;
}

ifstream file("bar.txt");
if (!file)
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to open bar.txt");

string line;
while (getline(file, line)) { // each line is a foo
    istringstream stream(line); // not efficient, but easy
    foo obj;
    if (stream >> obj) {
        // do something with the foo
    }
    if (!stream.eof()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("too much data?");
    }
}
```

Comment: My compiler won't allow `if` as an identifier :)

Comment: Haha, sure, I'll change that.